# Weird space before each bibliography in beamer

Tags: spacing, bibliographies, citing

I get this weird space in `[]` before my bibliography inputs. How can I remove this and just keep the number or `[1]` format?

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,9pt]{beamer}


\mode<presentation>
{
\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{background.jpg}}
}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
%\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{}
\definecolor{stevens}{RGB}{163,38,56}
\definecolor{stevensPPT}{RGB}{177,44,61}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=stevens}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=stevens!10}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=stevens!20}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded]
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\let\olditem=\item% 
\renewcommand{\item}{\olditem \justifying}%
\apptocmd{\frame}{}{\justifying}{}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}
\begin{itemize}
\item text 1 (\cite{leon1})
\item text2 (\cite{leon2})
\end{itemize}
\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Bibliography}
\small{\bibliographystyle{abbrv} }
\bibliography{references.bib}
\end{frame}
\begin{document}
```

references.bib file:

```
@article{leon1,
 ISSN = {00346535, 15309142},
 URL = {http://www.jstor.org/stable/1927837},
 author = {Wassily W. Leontief},
 journal = {The Review of Economics and Statistics},
 number = {3},
 pages = {105--125},
 publisher = {The MIT Press},
 title = {Quantitative Input and Output Relations in the Economic Systems of the United States},
 urldate = {2022-05-16},
 volume = {18},
 year = {1936}
}

@Book{leon2,
  editor={Leontief, Wassily},
  title={{Input-Output Economics}},
  publisher={Oxford University Press},
  year=1986,
  month={},
  volume={},
  number={9780195035278},
  series={OUP Catalogue},
  edition={},
  keywords={},
  doi={},
  isbn={ARRAY(0x537dfda8)},
  url={https://ideas.repec.org/b/oxp/obooks/9780195035278.html}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Remove the two lines `\let\olditem=\item` and `\renewcommand{\item}{\olditem \justifying}`. This messes up the bibliography entries that apparently also use `\item`. BTW, have you tried your sample code? It does not compile, since `\begin{item}...\end{item}` should be `\begin{itemize}...\end{itemize}`, and the last line should read `\end{document}` (instead of `\begin{document}`).

Comment: Ah perfect, thanks! Just edited the ```itemize```. @gernot

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, redefining `\item` is having unintended consequences on the bibliography, since the `\bibitem` command used in the bibliography file contains commands defined in terms of `\item`.

One possibility might be to patch those commands to use `\olditem` instead:

```
\let\olditem=\item% 
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@lbibitem}{\item}{\olditem}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@bibitem}{\item}{\olditem}{}{}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\item}{\olditem \justifying}%
```